# How to reference user account in FreeIPA database to user account in Web app database

Tags: django, wordpress, single-sign-on, freeipa

My company has decided to use `FreeIPA` in order to make available `Single Sign On` feature for our employees. I am not familiar at all with `Kerberos`/`LDAP` and similar because i have never used those technologies before.

We have 70 users - they have Windows OS machines and SSO should be used for several `Python` (`Django`) web apps, WordPress web sites and possibly for `Roundcube` web email and `OpenVPN` access. They don't have access to web servers at all so SSH accounts are not important for this story.

Our `python` web app has database table with users' data which is in relation with some other tables and it is very important for us to have every single user added to those tables (via our web app interface) because otherwise our app will not work properly.
Having that in mind, i would like to know if there is a way somehow to reference user from `FreeIPA's` database to our web app's and wordpress' databases, example below:
[image]

Not every user has access to every web app and not every user has the same privileges in those apps.

We have already defined user privileges in every web app separately and everything works perfect, so main aim is just to make avaliable `SSO` for our users. I don't want to bother with user groups and privileges in `FreeIPA` system, will be i able to avoid that?
When user gets `Kerberos` ticket i want those web apps to recognize his/her account which is referenced to corresponding user account in `FreeIPA` database, and so has certain privileges in those apps.

In this scenario it is obvious that i will have to add every new user two times - in `FreeIPA` database and in web app's database, but that's not a problem, i just want to connect/reference those user accounts somehow.

**EDIT to Michael Ströder's answer**:

As i see, i would have to add every existing user manually to FreeIPA with "--uid" command because FreeIPA gives those attributes to every user automatically. I agree, i would not use user names for UID but only integers. So, i have imagined to make it like this - i would have to link every user's uid number to application's DB user's table ID column. Let say, if John has UID #7 he should also have ID #7 in WordPress wp_users table, and that looks fine to me. I think i could easily manage this in my custom python app, but i'm unsure how to manage this in WordPress, is there some plugin that could be use for such things? I've found AuthLDAP but i'm not sure if that is the right way to do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to have unique and persistent **user names** (String), usually stored in attribute *uid* in FreeIPA (or other LDAP servers) and use this as key in your application's DB table.

Note that *uid* does **not** contain the POSIX-UID (Integer) which is actually stored in attribute *uidNumber*.

I'd strongly recommend **not** to derive user names stored in *uid* from personal names because these often change. Also you should never reuse user names.

FreeIPA also has attribute *nsUniqueId* which contains a UUID generated during creation of the entry. It will not be modified during life-time of the entry. If you want to use that you have to take care that entries are not deleted/re-created by an external identity management systems all the time.
(Other LDAP servers are using standard attribute [entryUUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4530)).

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question! This looks like reasonable way to do it. I've saw your answer few minutes after you have posted it and i've been late with my answer so much because i have been trying last two days to implement that but i'm still unable to do it. Because there is a text limit in these comments i will edit my question and give some additional details and i would really appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: I've added a note about POSIX-UID in my answer.